# Altium Designer 19.1.5: very dark 3D preview, black footprints

Tags: altium, footprint, 3d

Anyone facing the same issue? How this could be fixed? Tried to do a clean install, but it doesn't help. I'm on Windows 10 with all the recent updates.

[image: altium dark 3d preview]

[image: altium black footprints]

Comment: That looks a bit like a single-layer view. Did you try pressing Shift-S a few times?
If you did your clean install, did you also remove all configuration files that might have been just loaded again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallels 15 started to support DirectX, so the problem is gone after I upgraded Parallels to the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it's due to Parallels VM which I use for running Windows 10 & Altium on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Since this version is relatively new, I wouldn't rule out a bug. 
I am currently using 19.0.14 and have no problems.

The only thing I could image that your graphics card does not support DirectX 10.

Check here the System requirements: 
https://www.altium.com/documentation/19.1/display/ADES/Altium+Designer+-+((System+Requirements))